# Redirect when custom login panel is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

My custom login is empty [image: (screen)] when i click "Zaloguj się" wordpress redirect me to wordpress login panel. I want redirect to home page. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

How About This ? Redirect To Home Page After Successfull Login :

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $url, $query, $user ) {
   return home_url();
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: no :( when password and login fields (look screen its custom login) are empty and you will click "login" then WP redirect You to WP login page. I want change this page on home page for example ... i hope you understand

Comment: Then you have to use javascript/jquery method to redirect and to ignore Wordpress Default action.